# Opensearch 1.2.3 performance Analyzer api metrics answer response empty

Tags: opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I need to use the opensearch helath metrics.
In the documenteation it's mentioned to use the api as follows:

[https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/pa/api/#sample-request][1]

On my local dev system, using the API from the example, from the site, the metrics response are empty.

The GET API:
curl 'x.x.x.x:9600/_plugins/_performanceanalyzer/metrics?metrics=Latency,CPU_Utilization&agg=avg,max&dim=ShardID&nodes=all'

The response:

> {
> "local": {
> "timestamp": 1653829475000,
> "data": {
> "fields": [
> {
> "name": "ShardID",
> "type": "VARCHAR"
> },
> {
> "name": "Latency",
> "type": "DOUBLE"
> },
> {
> "name": "CPU_Utilization",
> "type": "DOUBLE"
> }
> ],
> "records": []
> }
> }
> }

While it should look like like something like this:

> {
> "keHlhQbbTpm1BYicficEQg": {
> "timestamp": 1554940530000,
> "data": {
> "fields": [{
> "name": "ShardID",
> "type": "VARCHAR"
> },
> {
> "name": "Latency",
> "type": "DOUBLE"
> },
> {
> "name": "CPU_Utilization",
> "type": "DOUBLE"
> }
> ],
> "records": [
> [
> null,
> null,
> 0.012552206029147535
> ],
> [
> "1",
> 4.8,
> 0.0009780939762972104
> ]
> ]
> }
> },
> "bHdpbMJZTs-TKtZro2SmYA": {
> "timestamp": 1554940530000,
> "data": {
> "fields": [{
> "name": "ShardID",
> "type": "VARCHAR"
> },
> {
> "name": "Latency",
> "type": "DOUBLE"
> },
> {
> "name": "CPU_Utilization",
> "type": "DOUBLE"
> }
> ],
> "records": [
> [
> null,
> 18.2,
> 0.011966493817311527
> ],
> [
> "1",
> 14.8,
> 0.0007670829370071493
> ]
> ]
> }
> }
> }

I would like to understnad what should I do to get those metrics populated.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 0):

After enabling the plugin (tested in Opensearch 1.3.6) it started to work

```
curl -XPOST "xxxxx:9200/_performanceanalyzer/cluster/config" -d '{"enabled": true}'
```

```
curl -XGET  "xxxx:9600/_plugins/_performanceanalyzer/metrics?metrics=Latency,CPU_Utilization&agg=avg,max&dim=ShardID&nodes=all"
{"Cpu2yu5KQjKqjrs085Y7ew": {"timestamp": 1666780920000, "data": {"fields":[{"name":"ShardID","type":"VARCHAR"},{"name":"Latency","type":"DOUBLE"},{"name":"CPU_Utilization","type":"DOUBLE"}],"records":[[null,null,0.020016996996996998]]}}, "cBkdsc8eR_C81KfPqmcCxg" :{"timestamp": 1666780920000, "data": {"fields":[{"name":"ShardID","type":"VARCHAR"},{"name":"Latency","type":"DOUBLE"},{"name":"CPU_Utilization","type":"DOUBLE"}],"records":[[null,null,0.0020227954409118174]]}}, "-J5PdpSORi-7oaa619CjZA" :{"timestamp": 1666780920000, "data": {"fields":[{"name":"ShardID","type":"VARCHAR"},{"name":"Latency","type":"DOUBLE"},{"name":"CPU_Utilization","type":"DOUBLE"}],"records":[[null,null,0.03806364835164835]]}}}%
```